# Disconnected from MQTT Brokers.NormalDisconnection

Tags: virtual-machine, mqtt, mosquitto, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to access Mosquitto mqtt broker from IoT Edge Runtime Module.
With MQTT URI as Virtual Machine IP and Port 1883.

But while running the module i am getting

Disconnected from MQTT Brokers.NormalDisconnection

Comment: Please update your question with the steps you've tried yourself. Please include configuration, code samples or anything else that might help people unfamiliar with your setup.

Comment: The log file from the Mosquitto Broker showing the disconnect would be good to see....otherwise there is not enough info here to help you.